# Reddit Get Subscriber Count Growth

Tags: reddit

Having a history of the subscriber count of specific subreddit is data that I need for data analysis.

I found a page which is doing exactly that e.g.: http://redditmetrics.com/r/worldnews

Is there an official endpoint in the reddit api for getting a history of subscriber counts and how the popularity of a subreddit has evolved until now or are there any other reliable ways to do this?

Tracking the data on my own is not an option because I'm interested in subscriber counts in the past and not in the future past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no endpoint for that within the [reddit api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/). One option could be to scrape sites like that for past data (with permission hopefully). And maybe the only other option would be to ask those sites for raw data (who knows, it might work). Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I will look at some projects and ask for permession - maybe some provide an undocumented api.